# Custom columns in kendo-angular2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am developing an Kendo-angular2 grid and I am planning to have custom columns in that. The grid structure is as below. But for some columns, I want custom styling.

```
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridData" [pageSize]="10" [pageable]="true" [sortable]="true" [groupable]="true" [height]="370">

    <template ngFor [ngForOf]="columns" let-column>

        <kendo-grid-column field="{{column}}"></kendo-grid-column>
    </template>

</kendo-grid>
```

Comment: could you specify what some of the custom headers could look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to implement it with kendoGridCellTemplate

```
   <kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridData">
            <kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let column of columns" [field]="column">
                <template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
                <span [class.special]="column.field === 'CompanyName'">  {{column.field}}({{columnIndex}})</span>
                </template>
                   <template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                  <span [class.special]="column === 'CompanyName'">  {{dataItem[column]}}</span>
                </template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
```

For more information: 
http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/#toc-templates
http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/CellTemplateDirective/

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/e2WX53zdOL9ioshWMIZO?p=preview

Comment: They want to have some custom columns, not custom cells

Comment: Custom columns that I am looking would be like, In my grid I am looking for a column with the values displayed in bold. And/or a column's data to have a different color.  Here how can I specify the "If" condition for the column name for which I want special styling. The special styling is for the content of the column but not the column header.

Comment: There I edited the answer to have a class added incase the name is x name. I did this because ngIf is just spammy

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Please correct me if I am wrong. So here for column name 'Special', you are trying to display the content of that column in red color. But it didn't work. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: It is exactly that. Maybe you just wrote 'Special' instead of 'special'? you can do {{column | json }} to look whats inside the column variable

Comment: I used my actual column name ContactTitle as shown below.  <span [class.red]="column.field == 'ContactTitle'">
              {{column.field}}({{columnIndex}})
           </span>. I am not sure what I am missing. It is displaying as before without any special styling applied to this column.

Comment: Note its a class...not a style. So there is no style to set it to red unless you write in your css

Comment: Yes I added that class. Is it because of the condition syntax? I also tried replacing that with *ngIf but it didn't work. I know we are very close but missing something very small.

Comment: did you try to {{column | json}} like I said?

Comment: Yes. It is displaying the entire grid just like before. There is no change even if I use the template tag or not..

Comment: Removed field attribute?

Comment: Yes even if the field attribute is removed.

Comment: I have created a plunker for reference.http://plnkr.co/edit/X6CwdJqwtL7mu4x4z2k0?p=preview

Comment: Take a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/m0Rui04uTh0lcACYTfXI?p=preview I copied straight from the angular2 docs

Comment: I already had a look at this plnkr this morning. I think my case is little different. Did you get a chance to see my plnkr and played little to get one column content in a different style.

Comment: Yes I did exactly that...I just changed your plunker to get mine

Comment: By any chance did you post a wrong plnkr path? Because when I run your plnkr I see a grid with three columns all with the same style. Sorry for troubling you a lot.

Comment: Oh to be honest, I just checked to see if the templates work and forgot to actually change the style. Here is the updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/e2WX53zdOL9ioshWMIZO?p=preview

Comment: I see the CompanyName column header changed to red. But actually I am trying for a different styling for the content but not header. I tried changing the kendoGridHeaderTemplate to kendoGridColumnTemplate, but it didn't work.

Comment: funnily enough the answer I first put was about cell and not header. I updated the plunker.Hopefully I helped you through and through

Comment: Appreciate your effort a lot.